# How to get a value of a table cell which was created using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I got a DataTable which is created like this:

```
table4 = $('#table').DataTable({
          ajax: "url.php"
          ...
         "columnDefs": [
                    {
                        "render": function (data, type, row) {
                            return '<center><button onclick="MyFunction();">myButton</button></center>';
                        },
                        "targets": 6
                    }
                ]
            });
```

Which means the 6th column is composed of buttons.
What I want to do is getting inside `MyFunction` the data inside the first cell (column 0) in the same row that the button was pressed. How can I get that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I eventually did was to make sure that in the file that outputs the data to the data table (`url.php`) is echoing what I need in the 7th place and then when it gets to the line:

```
"render": function (data, type, row) {
```

the "data" parameter already holds the data I need.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    var value = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child').text();
});
```

I prefer doing it this way instead of specifying the onclick attribute. Otherwise you can:

```
function MyFunction() {
    var value = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child').text();
}
```

Comment: I will try it soon but is there also a way of getting ith column? (could also be column 1 or 2 for example)

Comment: You can use the :eq selector for that: `var value = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `myfunction` use `.on` function https://api.jquery.com/on/ This can handle elements made by javascript after page is renedered.

`$( "#table" ).on( "click", "button", function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').get(0);
});`

Answer (score 0):

See your button is dynamically created so you need to pass `this` in the args like:

```
return '<center><button class='myButton' onclick="MyFunction(this);">myButton</button></center>';
```

Now in your function:

```js
function MyFunction(elem){
    //the data inside the first cell (column 0)
    var tr = $(elem).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
    console.log(tr);
}
```

or i like unobtrusive way:

add a class name to the button and use event delegation technique to bind the event to the dynamically created button element in the DOM:

```
$('#table').on('click', '.myButton', function(e){
    //the data inside the first cell (column 0)        
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
    console.log(tr);
});
```

Here in the snippet above you can replace `$('#table')` with `$(document), $(document.body) or $('body')` to delegate the event to the static parent.